# What is the least painful way to extract data at the protocol layer in Java?

Tags: java, network-programming, byte

I'm trying to implement an Android application to connect to the open source software Motion. The goal is to be able to check the status of the application and get the last image captured.

I do not program in Java very much, my background is principally in C and Python. I've not had any real issues with understanding the UI part of Android, but I've found it to be incredibly painful to work with any sort of byte buffer. The Motion software has an HTTP API that is very simple. Opening the URL connection is easy in Java. The response from the default page looks like this

```
Motion 3.2.12 Running [4] Threads
0
1
2
3
```

For my purposes the first thing the application needs to do it parse out the number of threads. At some point I can also retrieve the version number from the first line, but that's not really important presently.

Here's my code

```
package com.hydrogen18.motionsurveillanceviewer;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.List;

public class MotionHttpApi {
    String host;
    int port = 80;
    boolean secure = false;

    int numberOfThreads = -1;

    String getBaseUrl()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(secure ? "https://" : "http://");
        sb.append(host);
        sb.append(':');
        sb.append(port);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getNumberOfCameras() throws IOException
    {
        if(numberOfThreads == -1)
        {
            retrieveSplash();
        }

        if(numberOfThreads == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return numberOfThreads - 1;
    }
    void retrieveSplash () throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL(getBaseUrl());

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        if(conn.getResponseCode()!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            throw new IOException("Got response code" + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        try{
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[512];
            byte[] sbuf = new byte[128];
            int offset = 0;
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            boolean foundInfoString= false;
            while( ! foundInfoString)
            {
                //Check to make sure we have not run out of space
                if(offset == buffer.length)
                {
                    throw new IOException("Response too large");
                }

                //Read into the smaller buffer since InputStream
                //can't write to a Byte[]
                final int result = in.read(sbuf,0,sbuf.length);

                //Copy the data into the larger buffer
                for(int i = 0; i < result;++i)
                {
                    buffer[offset+i] = sbuf[i];
                }
                //Add to the offset
                offset+=result;

                //Wrap the array as a list
                List<Byte> list = java.util.Arrays.asList(buffer);  

                //Find newline character
                final int index = list.indexOf((byte) '\n');

                //If the newline is present, extract the number of threads
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    //Find the number of threads
                    //Thread number is in the first lin like "[X]"
                    final int start = list.indexOf((byte)'[');
                    final int end = list.indexOf((byte)']');

                    //Sanity check the bounds
                    if(! (end > start))
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Couldn't locate number of threads");
                    }

                    //Create a string from the Byte[] array subset
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i = start+1; i != end; ++i)
                    {                   
                        final char c = (char) buffer[i].byteValue();
                        sb.append(c);
                    }
                    String numThreadsStr = sb.toString();

                    //Try and parse the string into a number
                    try
                    {
                        this.numberOfThreads = Integer.valueOf(numThreadsStr);
                    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Number of threads is NaN",e);
                    }

                    //No more values to extract
                    foundInfoString = true;
                }

                //If the InputStream got EOF and the into string has not been found
                //Then an error has occurred. 
                if(result == -1 && ! foundInfoString )
                {
                    throw new IOException("Never got info string");
                }
            }

        }finally
        {
            //Close the connection
            conn.disconnect();
        }

    }

    public MotionHttpApi(String host,int port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

The code works just fine when you call `getNumberOfCameras()`. But I think I must not be really understandings omething in terms of java, because the retrieveSplash method is far too complex.  I could do the same thing in just 10 or so lines of C or 1 line of Python. Surely there must be a saner way to manipulate bytes in java?

I think there are some style issues, like I probably should not be throwing IOException whenever the integer fails to parse. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: What about writing that method in C first, to translate it to Java thereafter.

Comment: @11684 I could do that, but I'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: My point is: you say you want to clean up the retrieveSplash() method (make it shorter, as I read it) and you say, too, you could write it shorter in C. So if you write your short C version and translate it as 'literally' possible to C it might be shorter. It is not so much a 'point' as a 'does it help if you try to...'

Comment: I admit my first comment was a bit poorly worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the retrieveSplash method considerably by using BufferedReader. Here's a simpler version of your function:

```
void retrieveSplash_simpler() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(getBaseUrl());
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    // open the connection
    conn.connect();
    // create a buffered reader to read the input stream line by line
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    // find number of threads
    String firstLine = reader.readLine();
    int x = firstLine.indexOf("[");
    int y = firstLine.indexOf("]");
    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < y) {
        try {
            numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(firstLine.substring(x+1, y));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // disconnect and throw exception
            conn.disconnect();
            throw new IOException("Couldn't locate number of threads");
        }
    } else {
        // disconnect and throw exception
        conn.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Couldn't locate number of threads");
    }

    // disconnect
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

I'd further clean up the above method by using try/catch/finally blocks at the appropriate places so that I don't have to duplicate that "conn.disconnect()". But I didn't do that here to keep it simple (try/catch/finally do become tricky sometimes...).

Comment: no idea how I woulf have ever figured that out on my on. This still seems so ineffecient just to extract a number from a result. So many object allocations for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Read the first line as Gautam Tandon suggested and then use a regex.
You can then check if the regex matches and even easily extract the number.

Regex' can be created at [http://txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=Motion%203.2.12%20Running%20%5B4%5D%20Threads&-7&-19&-5&-20&-1&2&-22&-21&-62&-63&15). I've already done that for you.
The page even creates Java, Pyhton, C, etc. files for you to work with.

```
// URL that generated this code:
// http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=Motion%203.2.12%20Running%20[4]%20Threads&-7&-19&-5&-20&-1&2&-22&-21&-62&-63&15 

import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="Motion 3.2.12 Running [4] Threads";

    String re1="(Motion)";  // Word 1
    String re2="( )";   // White Space 1
    String re3="(3\\.2\\.12)";  // MMDDYY 1
    String re4="( )";   // White Space 2
    String re5="(Running)"; // Word 2
    String re6="( )";   // White Space 3
    String re7="(\\[)"; // Any Single Character 1
    String re8="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re9="(\\])"; // Any Single Character 2
    String re10="( )";  // White Space 4
    String re11="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";    // Word 3

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String word1=m.group(1);
        String ws1=m.group(2);
        String mmddyy1=m.group(3);
        String ws2=m.group(4);
        String word2=m.group(5);
        String ws3=m.group(6);
        String c1=m.group(7);
        String int1=m.group(8);
        String c2=m.group(9);
        String ws4=m.group(10);
        String word3=m.group(11);
        System.out.print("("+word1.toString()+")"+"("+ws1.toString()+")"+"("+mmddyy1.toString()+")"+"("+ws2.toString()+")"+"("+word2.toString()+")"+"("+ws3.toString()+")"+"("+c1.toString()+")"+"("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+c2.toString()+")"+"("+ws4.toString()+")"+"("+word3.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}

//-----
// This code is for use with Sun's Java VM - see http://java.sun.com/ for downloads. 
//
// Paste the code into a new java application or a file called 'Main.java'
//
// Compile and run in Unix using:
// # javac Main.java 
// # java Main 
//
```

`String int1=m.group(8);` gives you the desired integer. Of course you can simplify the above code. It's way to verbose right now.